# Перегрузка << для vector c++

Tags: c++, vector, map, stl

Есть такой ассоциативный массив: `map<char, vector<bool> > table;`
Как перегрузить << для cout, чтоб я мог выводить такую конструкцию:

```
for (map<char, vector<bool> >::iterator itr = table.begin(); itr != table.end(); ++itr)
    {
        cout << itr->first << " : " << itr->second << endl;
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23397700/7485582

Answer (score 4):

Правильный ответ — никак.

Перегруженные операторы обязательно нужно располагать в том месте, где их найдет [argument-dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). Очень грубо говоря, это значит "в том же namespace, где объявлен класс (или его шаблонные аргументы)", в вашем случае это означает — в `namespace std`.

В `namespace std` нельзя добавлять свои функции, поэтому лучше отказаться от идеи с перегрузкой.

Или, если очень хочется, завернуть вектор в структуру и перегрузить оператор для структуры (в том неймспейсе, где вы ее объявите).

Вот что будет, если проигнорировать этот принцип, и положить оператор, например, в глобальный неймспейс:

Вот такой код работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<bool> &vec)
{
    for (const auto &b : vec)
        stream << b;
    return stream;
}

namespace A
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::vector<bool> vec = {1,0,1,1};
        std::cout << vec << '\n';
    }
}
```

А вот такой уже не работает, хотя мы просто добавили еще один `operator<<`, не связанный с `std::vector<bool>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const std::vector<bool> &vec)
{
    for (const auto &b : vec)
        stream << b;
    return stream;
}

namespace A
{
    struct B {};
    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& stream, B)
    {
        return stream;
    }

    void foo()
    {
        std::vector<bool> vec = {1,0,1,1};
        std::cout << vec << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Если перенести оператор в `namespace A`, все заработает. https://ideone.com/bPVwMw

Comment: Добавлю, что до C++20 можно было добавлять в `namespace std` некоторые специализации шаблонных функций. Но в данном случае это бы не помогло, хотя бы потому что `std::vector<bool>` не является пользовательским типом

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно просто дописать оператор

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const vector<bool>& vec);
```

Как именно должен работать этот оператор - зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. В простейшем варианте

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const vector<bool>& vec) {
    for(auto b: vec) stream << b;
    return stream;
    }
```